# Is purpose of doing Yognidra and Meditation same?

Tags: moksha, meditation, yog-nidra

Generally poeple relate [meditation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meditation) with [Moksha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moksha) as purpose. What should be purpose behind doing [Yognidra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoga_nidra)? Is Yognidra just for relaxing body?

Comment: yog nidra se sakshi bhaav aata hai, fir ham so kar bhi nahi sote